# Pact testing issue in Windows machine

Tags: testing, jestjs, integration-testing, e2e-testing, pact

While runing the pact testing in my Nextjs spa app, am facing the pact testing issue in windows machine
error : pact-node@10.17.2: Pact Binary Error: ..\node_modules@pact-foundation\pact\node_modules@pact-foundation\pact-node\standalone\win32-1.88.83\pact\lib\ruby\bin.real\ruby.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.

am using @pact-foundation versions are

- ```
  "@pact-foundation/pact": "9.17.2",
  ```
- ```
  "@pact-foundation/pact-node": "10.17.1",
  ```

and also am using Windows 10 Enterprise, 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Please help on issue

Answer (score 0):

That version of pact is quite old. It's possible it's not compatible with a recent version of windows. Please raise an issue on the pact core repo so we take review